# nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com:1

Tags: nginx

I have problem with nginx config for custom site, but I cannot figure out what's the problem.
I already have 2 websites running and I'm adding 3rd, and I have c/p and modified config file form one site, but I get error that server directive is not allowed in line 1.

Anyone can point me what could be wrong?

Below are c/p from nginx.conf and domain.com config files:

**nginx.conf**

```
# Generic startup file.
user  nginx;

#usually equal to number of CPUs you have. run command "grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l" to find it
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Keeps the logs free of messages about not being able to bind().
#daemon     off;

events {
        worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
#       rewrite_log on;

        include            /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type       application/octet-stream;
        access_log         /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        sendfile           on;
        keepalive_timeout  3;
#       tcp_nopush         on;
#       tcp_nodelay        on;
        gzip               on;

#php max upload limit cannot be larger than this
        client_max_body_size 13m;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for PHP.
        upstream php {
                #this should match value of "listen" directive in php-fpm pool
                server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#               server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        include sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**domain.com**

```
Custom site rules:

server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain.com *.domain.com;

    root /var/www/html/domain.com/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/html/domain.com;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a missing `}` in the previous config file?

Comment: @Drifter104 no it's not, it is inside http block

Comment: @RichardSmith no it's not, I have just reinstalled nginx, and again when I do nginx -t -c domian.com i get same thing but I can restart nginx service and eveything works

Comment: `nginx -t -c domian.com` is testing an incomplete configuration file.

Comment: @Drifter104 sorry for missleading, but these are 2 files, after 'Custom site rules:' is a new file

Comment: @RichardSmith darn man, I think you might be right. testing nginx.conf is not giving any errors.